# Rename all files with specific format which are in folder with specific name

Tags: bash, files, find, rename

In my project I have a lot of test files, which are named `*.ts`.
They are all in `__tests__` folders, but it can be `__tests__/test1.ts`, `__tests__/dir2/test2.ts` and so on.

I would like to rename those files to `*.test.ts`.

How could I do it?

Examples:

1. `project/src/__tests__/app.ts` -> `project/src/__tests__/app.test.ts`
2. `project/src/dashboard/__test__/start/login.ts` -> `project/src/dashboard/__test__/start/login.test.ts`

I succeeded on finding those files with:

```
find . -type f -path '*__tests__*.ts'
```

but no idea how to rename them.

Comment: added examples and my try

Comment: You can play with [`rename -nv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

Comment: @Aaron thx for replay. On the machine, where I need to do it, there's no "rename" program, and I can't install things there.

Comment: You can try [this solution on askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/35922)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `-exec` option to invoke a shell to perform the rename.

```
find . -type f -path '*__tests__*.ts' -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%ts}test.ts"
  done
' findsh {} +
```

- `-exec sh -c` Invokes a shell and runs:

  - `for f; do mv -- "$f" "${f%ts}test.ts"; done` Loops over the found files, renaming them to a target whose `ts` is removed and a `test.ts` is put on its place.
- In `findsh {} +`, `findsh` is just a placeholder and `{} +` is the construct that gives the files to the `-exec` command (the shell).